# Put result of cursor into table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

How i can put result rows of this cursor, into column ?

```
CURSOR CUR1 IS SELECT FILMS.FILM_CODE  from FILMS where FILMS.ID_FILM = ID_FILM_ FOR UPDATE OF FILM_CODE;
```

I wanna put this rows into FILM_CODE column of table below

```
CREATE TABLE SESSIONF(
ID_SESSION INTEGER DEFAULT SESSION_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
FILM_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL,
NAMEOFGENRE VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
HALL_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL,
NUMBEROFFREEPLACES INTEGER NOT NULL,
COST INTEGER NOT NULL,
DATA_OF_SESSION DATE,
CONSTRAINT  PK_ID_SESSION PRIMARY KEY (ID_SESSION)
)
TABLESPACE TBS_PERM_KINO;
```

Sorry if topic with the same issue already exist, couldn't find it.

**EDIT**
Procedure on update

```
create or replace procedure UpdateFILM(ID_FILM_ FILMS.ID_FILM%TYPE,FILM_CODE_ IN FILMS.FILM_CODE%TYPE,FILM_ IN FILMS.FILM%TYPE,GENRE_CODE_ FILMS.GENRE_CODE%TYPE,DIR_CODE_ FILMS.DIRECTOR_CODE%TYPE,YEAROFRELEAS_ FILMS.YEAROFRELEAS%TYPE)
is
    varible int := 0;
    varible2 int := 0;
    varible3 int := 0;
    varible4 int := 0;
    CURSOR CUR1 IS SELECT FILMS.FILM_CODE  from FILMS where FILMS.ID_FILM = ID_FILM_ FOR UPDATE OF FILM_CODE;
    F_CODE SESSIONF.FILM_CODE%TYPE; 
begin
    select count(*) INTO VARIBLE from FILMS where FILM_CODE_ = FILMS.FILM_CODE;
    select count(*) INTO VARIBLE2 from DIRECTORS where DIR_CODE_ = DIRECTORS.DIRECTOR_CODE;
    IF varible != 0
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('FILM_CODE_ erro : there is ALREADY THE SAME FILM_CODE');
    ELSIF varible2 =0
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('DIR_CODE_ ERR : there IS NO SUCH DIRECTOR_CODE');
    ELSIF varible3 !=0
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('GENRE_CODE_ ERR : there IS NO SUCH GENRE_CODE_');
    ELSIF TO_DATE('12/12/1941', 'DD/MM/YYYY') >  YEAROFRELEAS_
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('YEAROFRELEAS_ erro : DATE IS LESS THEN 1941');
    ELSIF TO_DATE('12/12/3000', 'DD/MM/YYYY') <  YEAROFRELEAS_
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('YEAROFRELEAS_ erro : DATE IS TO HIGH(MORE THEN 3000)');    
        ELSE     
        UPDATE FILMS SET
            FILMS.ID_FILM = ID_FILM_,
                FILMS.FILM_CODE = FILM_CODE_,
                    FILMS.FILM = FILM_,
                        FILMS.GENRE_CODE = GENRE_CODE_,
                          FILMS.DIRECTOR_CODE = DIR_CODE_,
                            FILMS.YEAROFRELEAS = YEAROFRELEAS_
                    WHERE   FILMS.ID_FILM = ID_FILM_;
        OPEN CUR1;
            LOOP
                FETCH CUR1 INTO F_CODE;
                    UPDATE SESSIONF SET SESSIONF.FILM_CODE=FILM_CODE_ WHERE F_CODE = SESSIONF.FILM_CODE;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(F_CODE);
              EXIT WHEN CUR1%NOTFOUND;
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE CUR1;               
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('films update successful');
    END IF;
    exception
    when others 
    then DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
CREATE sequence FILM_ID_SEQ;
CREATE TABLE FILMS (
ID_FILM INTEGER DEFAULT FILM_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
FILM_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL,
FILM VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
GENRE_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL,
DIRECTOR_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL,
YEAROFRELEAS DATE,
CONSTRAINT  PK_ID_FILM PRIMARY KEY (ID_FILM)
)
TABLESPACE TBS_PERM_KINO;
alter table SESSIONF add constraint FK_FILM_CODE_REF_ID_FILM foreign key (FILM_CODE) references FILMS (ID_FILM) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it, you can't do that.

Why? Because table contains numerous `NOT NULL` columns, while cursor selects only one column: `FILM_CODE`. You could store that value, but what will you put into other mandatory columns?

Therefore, you'll have to either fix cursor's `select` statement so that it fetches additional columns, or modify table and remove `not null` constraints (or, possibly, set `default` values for those columns).

---

On the other hand, why would you use a cursor? Cursor is usually slow (as you'll probably use it in a loop which works row-by-row). Consider

```
insert into sessionf (filmcode, nameofgenre, ...)
select f.filmcode, ...
from films f 
     join ... on ...
```

Comment: I have a procedure for updating the movie, there is also a table with the movie code - a table of sessions, when I update the movie code, I want to update all sessions with the past movie code to new ones, with an explicit cursor I select all lines with the old code, I want to change these results to the movie code that I have as a parameter, and apply these modified result rows to the session table, to be honest, I didn't understand at all what you were talking about at first, explain in understandable language.

Comment: You have to understand that we know nothing about your database. You posted one (target) table description and a cursor that selects only one column, and asked how to put results returned by that cursor into the table. I told you that you **can not** do that because of (now re-read what I already wrote).  I have no idea that you have a "procedure for updating the movie" nor "a table with the movie code", "a table of sessions" etc. etc. You never said anything about that while writing the question so - how are we supposed to compose answer that considers all of that?

Comment: my bad,sorry, edited the post

Comment: OK. First, you perform some controls and - if everything is OK, you update FILMS table and - in a cursor loop - update SESSIONF table. What is the problem? Did you get some errors, or did that code not do what you wanted, or ...?

Comment: the movie is updated across all fields, but the movie code in the session table is not updated, why is not clear, so I'm here to figure it out

Comment: Aha. It is the WHERE clause that instructs Oracle which rows to update. It is: `WHERE F_CODE = SESSIONF.FILM_CODE`. If no rows were updated, it means that not a single row in SESSIONF table has FILM_CODE that is equal to F_CODE. F_CODE gets its value as `FETCH CUR1 INTO F_CODE`, which means that cursor didn't return any row whose F_CODE exists in SESSIONF table. I can't try it myself, I don't have your data so you'll have to **debug** it. A simple option is to put dbms_output.put_Line calls and display values that exist at certain point of execution, until you find the culprit.

Comment: I checked, there is a line in the cursor

Comment: forget it, just drop film_code parameter....